# Send trigger from service to components

Tags: angular, ionic2

i have a AuthService in angular2. When the user hit's logout button. I want so send a signal to specific component's i.e: **home.ts** and **app.component.ts** that the user is logged-out.

My main goal is to update the page, with login button instead of profile photo button.

is it possible to send a trigger from AuthService(onchange) to specific components?

Kind regards,
Kab

Comment: you could think of using `Subject`(Observable) & subscribe it wherever you want.. Any update in stream can intimates its all subscriber

Answer (score 2):

Usually in similar situations I use a **session service** shared among all components via Dependency Injection.

The session service implements a `Subject` (`Observable`) as pointed out by Pankaj.

Any component interested in the Subject needs to have the **session service** injected and then subscribes to the `Observable`.

Any component that wants to signal the event, needs to have the **session service** injected and uses the `Observable` to fire the event via the `next()` method.

SessionService example:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class SessionService {
    private sessionDisable: boolean;
    private _sessionDisable = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    constructor() { }

    disableSession() {
        this.sessionDisable = true;
        this._sessionDisable.next(true);
    }

    enableSession() {
        this.sessionDisable = false;
        this._sessionDisable.next(false);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Picci, thanks for the answer. Is it possible to provide an example code or share your session service?